# Failing to compile and link PcapPlusPlus library with SYCL code

Tags: cmake, intel-oneapi, sycl, pcapplusplus

I want to use the C++ library [PcapPlusPlus](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/) and it‘s header files in my SYCL code. More exactly I want to compile it with the Intel C++ Compiler (`icpx`). I know how to program and know how C, Java and Python work but seem to have issues to work with C++ and using external libraries. I can't seem to make it work, to compile and link the library correctly. I tried it with CMake which I had to read into because I really had to use it the first time but more on this further down.

I am using CentOS Stream 8 and oneAPI Base Toolkit 2023.1 which I tested successfully with code that doesn't use 3rd party libraries.

So I downloaded the [Github repository](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus) because I have to build it myself for CentOS Stream 8. I put the files into my project folder and went into package to start the build of the library like in the [instructions](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/install/linux) with CMake and the compiler I want to use it with (icpx).

```
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpx -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/PcapPlusPlus
```

As the instructions say, build and install it.

```
cmake --build build
cmake --install build
```

After that I tried to compile the code example of PcapPlusPlus with the [instructions and CMake file they provide](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/quickstart). This worked but did not use the `icpx` compiler.

So I went ahead and searched on how I could link the libraries and header files with just using the `icpx` command in the CLI. I stumbled upon the parameters `-I` to add the path to the header files, `-L` for the libraries and `-l` to give the name of the library. PcapPlusPlus creates 3 static libraries.

```
icpx -I/path/to/installed/PcapPlusPlus/include -L/path/to/installed/PcapPlusPlus/lib -lCommon++ -lPacket++ -lPcap++ mysrc.cpp -o myexe
```

This command created a lot of "undefined reference" errors pointing at lines in the header files of `Packet.h`. `icpx` exits with the error:
`icpx: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`

Another try was to create a `CMakeLists.txt` file that uses the `icpx` compiler with the help of the [CMakeLists.txt of the example of PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/v23.09/Examples/ExampleApp/CMakeLists.txt) and [this documentation of Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-1/use-cmake-with-the-compiler.html). It resulted in the following `CMakeLists.txt` file

```cmake
if (CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)
    # need at least CMake 3.23 for IntelLLVM support of IntelSYCL package on Windows
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
else()
    # CMake 3.20.5 is the minimum recommended for IntelLLVM on Linux
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.5)
endif()

project(simple-sycl LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER icpx)
# popen()/pclose() are not C++ standards
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)

find_package(PcapPlusPlus REQUIRED)

add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" main.cpp)
# We want to have the binary compiled in the same folder as the .cpp to be near the PCAP file
set_target_properties("${PROJECT_NAME}" PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
# Link with Pcap++ libraries
target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" PUBLIC PcapPlusPlus::Pcap++)
```

I erased `find_package(IntelSYCL REQUIRED)` as it led to errors of not finding `IntelSYCL`

The command to start the `cmake` process was following:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpx -DPcapPlusPlus_ROOT=/path/to/PcapPlusPlus
```

This worked until the `find_package` line for the PcapPlusPlus package, as it creates a C-file which the `icpx` cannot read of course. When adding `C` to the `project()` it went through with no error but not creating a binary.

I also tried to use one of the oneAPI samples and modify the `CMakeLists.txt` and adding the lines to find the package with the same errors.

Now I am stuck because I can't seem to find a solution for this linking issue and was wondering what I am doing wrong or if it is possible to use the library.

Comment: "After that I tried to compile the code example of PcapPlusPlus with the instructions and CMake file they provide. This worked but did not use the icpx compiler." - Did you tell CMake to use the Intel compilers (`-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpx`) when compiling the example as well?

Comment: "When adding "C" to the project() it went through with no error but not creating a binary." - Did you maybe forget to actually build after configuring using `cmake`?

Comment: "This worked until the `find_package` line for the PcapPlusPlus package, as it creates a C-file which the `icpx` cannot read of course." The output would be interesting because I don't think that one generally needs to add the language of external libraries. `find_package`/the packaging of PcapPlusPlus should define what language it uses. By "C-file" you mean a `.c`? Why would `icpx` need to read such a file when it only needs to link against the external library? Generally C++ compilers have no problem with reading C-files, be that `.c` or `.h`.

Comment: "Did you tell CMake to use the Intel compilers (-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpx) when compiling the example as well?"
- I did not before. I tried it now and it is searching for header files at the path `/usr/local/include/pcapplusplus` with the line `target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" PUBLIC PcapPlusPlus::Pcap++)`. I thought the the parameter `-CPcapPlusPlus_ROOT=/path/to/PcapPlusPlus` would solve this but apparently not.
Now it works with to compile it with icpx! Now the next issue is how to integrate the `IntelSYCL` package, as it throws errors.

Comment: "Did you maybe forget to actually build after configuring using `cmake`?"
- I did, learned that after posting. With the `make` command it started building and linking but not successfully with known issues that I previously had with just using the `icpx` command

Comment: "The output would be interesting because I don't think that one generally needs to add the language of external libraries." - That is what I thought too, but without adding the "C" in `project()` it was not able to compile the chaos of files and paths I created.
"By "C-file" you mean a `.c`?" - Yes, I don't understand what exactly is happening when I don't use the exact `CMakeLists.txt` from the PcapPlusPlus example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

So with some help of @paleonix (thank you) and an idea I have come to an easy solution.

First of all, what I noticed that `find_package(PcapPlusPlus REQUIRED)` needs, is the header files in the path `/usr/local/include/pcapplusplus` so I copied them from the installation folders into there.

OneAPI has its own example projects and come with their `CMakeLists.txt` which is easier to build upon and add the needed lines from the PcapPlusPlus library.

### Modifications to the Code

So I choose the [vector-add](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/tree/master/DirectProgramming/C%2B%2BSYCL/DenseLinearAlgebra/vector-add) example, downloaded it and replaced the code in `src/vector-add-buffers.cpp` with the code of the [PcapPlusPlus example](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/v23.09/Examples/ExampleApp/main.cpp). Keeping includes for `sycl/sycl.hpp` and `<sycl/ext/intel/fpga_extensions.hpp>` as that is what I need later on.

### Modifications to the CMakeLists.txt files

The first modification has to be made in [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/blob/master/DirectProgramming/C%2B%2BSYCL/DenseLinearAlgebra/vector-add/CMakeLists.txt) to prevent the issue that the `detect_pcap_version.c` can't be read. Therefore the line:

`project(VectorAdd CXX)` needs a "C" added to it and should look like `project(VectorAdd CXX C)`

Next in the [src/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/blob/master/DirectProgramming/C%2B%2BSYCL/DenseLinearAlgebra/vector-add/src/CMakeLists.txt) needs to be added the `find_package(PcapPlusPlus REQUIRED)` line. I placed it in `SECTION 1` right above the `add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILE})`.

Also it needs the line `target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC PcapPlusPlus::Pcap++)` after the `set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${LINK_FLAGS}")` line. This slightly modified function from the PcapPlusPlus example needs to be added in each `SECTION` with the according `TARGET_NAME` variable.

### Build

The next step is following oneAPIs instructions in the [README.md](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/blob/master/DirectProgramming/C%2B%2BSYCL/DenseLinearAlgebra/vector-add/README.md) to build the project and adding the compiler parameters to the `cmake` command:

1. `mkdir build`
2. `cd build`
3. `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpx ..`

With these steps a Makefile should be created in this `build` folder which can now be executed. As the [README.md](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/blob/master/DirectProgramming/C%2B%2BSYCL/DenseLinearAlgebra/vector-add/README.md) states, one can choose from the options, for this example I used `make cpu-gpu` and wait until the process finishes.

## Execute

Now that the binary is created. To use it, we still need the [pcap](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/v23.09/Examples/ExampleApp/1_packet.pcap) of PcapPlusPlus placed in this folder. With `./vector-add-buffers` it executes successfully as SYCL code.